# Magento 2 - Not updating CSS

Tags: magento2, theme, css

I have my magento 2 site in develop mode and have disabled the cache but my theme is not picking up changes to my css file.

Is there anyway to update the css without the need to:

```
Remove pub/static [keep the .htaccess]
Remove var/cache
Remove var/generation
Remove var/page_cache
Remove var/view_preprocessed
run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: First, check you can see your updated `css` in from browser URL if not then please do `CTRL + F5` and check.

Comment: Yeah its not updating and showing my old css, clearing browser cache doesn't resolve this. I have to run the above commands to be able to get the css to be the latest version.

Comment: Have you check in current theme? Can you tell me CSS path which you try in browser?

Answer (score 1):

I'll suppose that you have a custom theme and you have this theme assigned to store in admin.

If you have created a plain css file you need to add it in theme layout file, if you had overriden less files you might use grunt:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html